# Remove shortcodes that are different (but same pattern) in each post

Tags: shortcode, mysql, regex

I have unused shortcodes in my posts like the following:

```
[wp-imageflow2 dir=NokiaN868MP176]

[wp-imageflow2 dir=Nokia6303classic97]

[wp-imageflow2 dir=LGOptimus3DCubeSU87026]
```

How do I remove them all via some search & replace plugin or MySQL query?

I would need to do the search and remove or search and replace while using regex for NokiaN868MP176, Nokia6303classic97, LGOptimus3DCubeSU87026 but not sure how to make one properly.

Comment: There are several plugins that will do this for you. Unfortunately we don't do product recommendations here at WPSE, but Google will surely help you if you ask "search replace wordpress".

Comment: I know about the plugins but not sure which regex i need to run to properly match all the shortcodes.